# How can I eject an external Mac HDD on Windows if it is not showing up in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, mac

I'm reading an external Mac HDD on Windows 10. It doesn't show up in my Windows Explorer but using HFSExplorer, I was able to transfer my files to Windows.

How can I eject this external HDD if it is not showing up in Windows Explorer. It doesn't register in the taskbar either.

I don't want to reinstall drivers to accomplish this.

Comment: If you only read from the drive, there may not be a need to eject it.  But it is always safe to remove the drive after you close Windows and power down.

Comment: I transferred files to my windows, still no need?

Comment: The reason for ejecting is that if you write to the drive, you want to be sure that you don't remove it before writing is complete (sometimes content is postponed to be written later, or moving a lot of data may take awhile).  When you eject, it flushes any stored data and completes the writing, and then confirms that it is safe to remove.  But if you only read from the drive and write to somewhere else, you haven't changed anything on the drive.